# How can I load images from Firebase Storage using the download token?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I made an app using Flutter, and I want to load some images from the Firebase Storage. I got the Download Token for every picture I have. How can I load an image by using that Download token.

For now, I'm displaying that image like this

```
Image.network('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/****-****.appspot.com/o/fileName?alt=media&token=downloadToken'),
```

In my database I only saved the Download Token and not both Download Token and Image Name. I load the document that stores the Download Token by using a StreamBuilder, I need all the data be live and as I display other fields in my Column I want to display that image too.

I know in Android I could have loaded an image only by it's Download Token.

It is possible here too?

If yes, could you help me implement that?

Comment: You're not really supposed to work with the token alone.  You're supposed to use `getDownloadURL` with the path of the file to get a the full URL that automatically includes the token. https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/StorageReference/getDownloadURL.html

Comment: thank you very much ill try that